# Sharp shooter 'called shot' hit penalty

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

In 5E can the sharp shooter feat's "-5 to hit" penalty for the "called shot" be offset by proficiency, ability or other related bonuses?  In other words, must it always be a -5 to hit at least or can it be lowered to nothing or even brought back to a bonus?

Comment: A "-5 to hit" means you reduce your normal to hit roll bonus by 5 points, it doesn't mean you roll a d20-5. If that's not what you were asking about, can you make it a little clearer what you want to know?

Comment: It's not a called shot, and  there is not in the core rules a called shot in D&D 5e.  I'd suggest not using that term in your question, as it may lead to confusion by people reading this question and answers.

Answer (score 13):

Your interpretation might be a little off, let's take a look at the skill description:

> Sharpshooter
>   You have mastered ranged weapons and can make shots
>   that others find impossible. You gain the following benefits:
>       Attacking at long range doesn't impose disadvantage on your ranged weapon attack rolls.
>       Your ranged weapon attacks ignore half cover and three-quarters cover.
>       **Before you make an attack with a ranged weapon that you are proficient with, you can choose to take a -5 penalty to the attack
>   roll. If the attack hits, you add +10 to the attack’s damage.**

You just add a -5 modifier to your attack roll, you don't negate other modifiers such as Dextery, Fighting Style or Proficiency.